# chown: invalid group: ‘root:adm’ problem when installing apache2

Tags: software-installation, apache2, 22.04

I tried to install apache2 with `apt install apache2` but it didn't get fully installed, and I got this message:

```
chown: invalid group: ‘root:adm’
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried rebooting and still the same problem. I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Our SlickStack community is also aware of this error on certain cloud providers, we believe it might be caused by certain providers not properly setting up their Ubuntu images and `root` user permissions: https://slickstack.io/forum/topic/chown-invalid-group-rootadm-error-on-racknerd

Comment: TLDR you might need to ask your cloud provider to fix it, otherwise you might be stuck having to create group `adm` and adding `root` user into that group every time.

Answer (score 0):

`grep adm /etc/group`   do you have an adm group defined ?

`getent group | grep adm`    should also return something like

```
adm:x:4:
```

Debian and CentOS both a group called adm with a GID of 4, so its likely a standard.  Did you ever tweak your local groups ?

Comment: It returns nothing, and I haven't modified the groups. But I am using root

Comment: @IgnacioPozo the packaging the DEB is such that it expects a group of that name.  Did you add any package repositories to this host so its getting a deb from outside of the distro's tree ?

Comment: I don't know how to check that :(, but I haven't changed anything

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. @IgnacioPozo Did you solve this?

Comment: @RajithaBandara I had to downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. I thought that it might be a problem with the server provider, but never created a ticket for that

Comment: @IgnacioPozo That might be correct. What I did was creating adm group and adding root user to that group as I couldn't find other solution.